# Gemfile dependencies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

In a Rails application, if one of the gems included in a Gemfile depends on another one that I want to use, do I need to include the second one in a Gemfile?

Say, I use a `cucumber-rails` gem. By running `bundle dependency cucumber-rails`, I can see that it depends on 'database_cleaner' and `factory_girl`. Do I need to include the former two into the Gemfile or not?

Thanks!

Comment: If the gem requires these to gems to work I would assume that you need them, yes. Although see if it works without them, if not just include them in the gemfile and see if that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) then it will install any dependency when you install a gem

you can see the dependencies in `gemfile.lock`

but note that having a dependency installed is not always good to assume that the dependency installed is the gem version you want. The dependency installed is the version required for the gem to work. If you need factory-girl on the latest version (or any other version), then it is best to include it in the `gemfile`

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to explicitly require them in your Gemfile. Bundler will detect the dependencies, include them in your Gemfile.lock and install them.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look around and apparently you should not use the bundle dependency cucumber-rails install function:

https://makandracards.com/makandra/12741-don-t-update-gems-with-bundle-update-unless-you-re-feeling-lucky

Comment: that's what Gemnasium is for